# Is there a following sibling for CSS selectors

Tags: html, css-selectors

I am very new with CSS selectors and was wondering if there was something like a following sibling for them.

Example: I am trying to extract just the dates from this piece of code

```
<p class="premiumOnly">
<strong>Original bar admit date:</strong> 5/10/1974<br>
<strong>Colorado bar admit date:</strong> 5/10/1974
```

The selector 
`#Listing > div.col-sm-8.text-left.memberOnly > div.row > div.col-sm-7 > p:nth-child(4) > strong:nth-child(1)` is only getting the text **Original bar admit date** but not the actual dates

Kindly advise if there is a way to get the dates only. I can also accommodate a Regex along with the selector if needed

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by extract?

Comment: This is not "following sibling". It is "following text". There is no text selector in CSS.

Comment: CSS selectors help you select elements, which you can then manipulate and see the contents of. Your dates, as far as we can tell, are _not_ in distinct HTML elements, so there's nothing to actually select.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what library you're using to scrape this HTML. Right now everyone else is assuming you're styling elements using CSS (and I can't fault them - you did tag your question [css]).

Answer (score 3):

You will have to wrap the text you want to style with some `span` or other tag in order to select it.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting `strong:nth-child(1)` will just grab what's in the strong tag. I'm assuming `p:nth-child(4)` is `.premiumOnly` in your code. To extract just the dates, you can target that paragraph, and use regex and remove the stuff you don't want.

```js
var p = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML;
p = p.replace(/<strong>.*<\/strong>|<br>|\n/g,'');
console.log(p);
```

```html
<p class="premiumOnly" id="p">
  <strong>Original bar admit date:</strong> 5/10/1974<br>
  <strong>Colorado bar admit date:</strong> 5/10/1974
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your actual use-case is just as your example is, you should be able apply a style to the entire paragraph (dates and strong text), and then remove that style from the strong text. What you're left with is a style that only affects the dates.

For example, if you wanted to make the dates red... https://jsfiddle.net/1sdqoug5/

```css
    p.premiumOnly {
        color: red;
    }
    
    p.premiumOnly > strong {
        color: initial;
    }
```

```html
    <p class="premiumOnly">
      <strong>Strong Text: </strong> date<br>
      <strong>Strong Text 2: </strong> date
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exists indeed, the selector `A + B` matches any `B` element preceded by an `A` element. It is not of help in you case however, because the `strong` element has no immediate siblings. The date you want to extract is a text node.
You either wrap it in a `span` like 
`<strong>Original bar admit date:</strong> <span>5/10/1974</span`
so you can match it by selecting `strong + span`

or alternatively use the DOM or jQuery API to target the text node

Comment: well, in that case there is one way left, wrap the text He want to target in a span

Comment: @torazaburo: "extract" does mean "select", but not for styling purposes. As far as I'm aware, "extract" has only ever been used in the context of web scraping. If the asker is using Selenium WebDriver, then a JS solution is appropriate (although WebDriver has a dedicated method for extracting the text from the desired element anyway). Right now though the asker has made no mention of what tool or library they're using to scrape the HTML.

Comment: @torazaburo: ... OTOH if they really *are* limited to just CSS selectors, then they're probably out of luck, though I can't think of many situations in which a method or tool that only takes a selector string instead of running arbitrary code doesn't also accept XPath (which would be a completely viable alternative).